# strange timezone issue EDT/EST

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have checked my mysql system timezone with `SELECT @@system_time_zone;` and its return `EDT` in production server. Now I want to generate same timezone's (i.e EDT) current timestamp which is not working. This is what i have tried so far is

```
date_default_timezone_set('EST');
$ts = strtotime('now');
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$ts);
```

and

```
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('EST'));
$ts = $date->getTimestamp();
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',$ts);
```

its output is `2015-09-07 05:38:43` but my mysql date (timestamp) is `2015-09-07 06:39:53` so its not same. (tested by inserting same time)

So **how can I get current timestamp based on mysql's system time zone** (EDT/EST)?? any help from proessional appricated

Comment: Have you tried using `EST5EDT` instead of just `EST`?

Comment: @ESG checked, nothing happened.same result

Answer (score 0):

The current values of the global and client-specific time zones can be retrieved like this:

```
mysql> SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone;
```

And try to use this code to set time zone and Location of time zone

```
<?php
$date = date_create('2000-01-01', timezone_open('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";

date_timezone_set($date, timezone_open('Pacific/Chatham'));
echo date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
?
```

Note second php code is just an example.

I hope I helped you

Comment: I need timestamp based on mysql timezone not formatted date. I have shown formatted date for realizing that those are not same